# Find $\cos{\theta}$ and $\sin{\theta}$ such that the rotation through the acute angle $\theta$ results in a new equation with no $x'y'$ term

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find $\cos{\theta}$ and $\sin{\theta}$ such that the rotation through the acute angle $\theta$ results in a new equation with no $x'y'$ term
$$x^2-2xy+y^2-\sqrt{2}x-2\sqrt{y}+2=0$$

I'm not really sure what to do with his problem as I have not encountered one like it before.

I know that $x=x'\cos{\theta}-y'\sin{\theta}$ and $y=x'\sin{\theta}+y'\cos{\theta}$

Do I need to come up with an angle that when I make the substitution it will cancel everything out resulting in no $x'y'$ terms? Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what you’re supposed to do.

Comment: Are you sure that the next-to-last term is really $2\sqrt y$ and not $\sqrt 2y$?

Comment: Thats how it was written it may have been a mistake though since it was a hand written problem that someone showed me.

Comment: Hint: Assuming that it was really meant to be $\sqrt2 y$, observe that the equation is symmetric in $x$ and $y$. Does this suggest an angle to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the product
$$
 xy = \left( x' \cos \theta - y' \sin \theta \right)
 \left( x' \sin \theta + y' \cos \theta \right)
$$
The cross term looks like this
$$ 
 x'y' \left( \cos^{2}\theta - \sin^{2}\theta\right)
$$
You are asked to solve for $\theta$
$$
 \cos^{2}\theta - \sin^{2}\theta = 0
$$